# libuv based server crash when there are two connections back to back

Tags: linux, networking, libuv

Doing some research on high performance TCP server (not necessarily for HTTP) for testing purpose. Followed some sample code and created a libuv based TCP server, however the following sample code will crash with error SIGPIPE on the line `uv_write(req, stream, buffer, 1, on_write);`.  Here is the console output:

```
client=0x562529924700
1writing to 0x562529924700
2writing to 0x562529924700
wrote.
1writing to 0x562529924700
```

Note that the tcp client closes the first tcp connection with TCP RESET. Wireshark shows that the TCP client has established the second tcp connection and sent the request, but the tcp server somehow didn't print something similar to the line `client=0x562529924700` to indicate that it has accept the second connection.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is the server code

```
//from https://gist.github.com/Jxck/4305806
//     https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/networking.html
//api guide http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uv.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define DEFAULT_PORT 8080
#define DEFAULT_BACKLOG 1000

uv_loop_t *loop;
int cnt = 0;
char *str = "HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\r\nContent-Length: 7\r\n\r\n%07d\n";

void on_write(uv_write_t* req, int status)
{
    if (status) {
        perror( "uv_write error ");
        return;
    }
    printf("wrote.\n");
    free(req);
    //uv_close((uv_handle_t*)req->handle, on_close);
}

void write2(uv_stream_t* stream, char *data, int len2) {
    uv_buf_t buffer[] = {
            {.base = data, .len = len2}
    };
    uv_write_t *req = malloc(sizeof(uv_write_t));
    printf("1writing to %p\n", stream);
    uv_write(req, stream, buffer, 1, on_write);
    printf("2writing to %p\n", stream);
}
void on_close(uv_handle_t* handle)
{
    //printf("closed.");
}
void echo_read(uv_stream_t *sock, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t *buf) {
    if (nread == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error echo_read");
        return;
    } else if (nread == 0) {
        uv_close((uv_handle_t*)sock, on_close);
        return;
    }
    char respMsg[52];
    sprintf(respMsg, str, cnt++);
    //snprintf(&respMsg[41],  6,"%6d", cnt++);
    write2(sock, respMsg, strlen(respMsg));
    //printf("result: %s\n", buf->base);
}
static void my_alloc_cb(uv_handle_t* handle, size_t suggested_size, uv_buf_t* buf) {
    buf->base = malloc(suggested_size);
    buf->len = suggested_size;
}

void on_new_connection(uv_stream_t *server, int status) {
    if (status < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "New connection error %s\n", uv_strerror(status));
        // error!
        return;
    }

    uv_tcp_t *client = (uv_tcp_t*) malloc(sizeof(uv_tcp_t));
    printf("client=%p\n", client);
    uv_tcp_init(loop, client);
    if (uv_accept(server, (uv_stream_t*) client) == 0) {
        uv_read_start((uv_stream_t*) client, my_alloc_cb, echo_read);
    }
    else {
        printf("failed to accept\n");
        uv_close((uv_handle_t*) client, NULL);
    }
}

int main() {
    loop = uv_default_loop();

    uv_tcp_t server;
    uv_tcp_init(loop, &server);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", DEFAULT_PORT, &addr);
    int r;
    r = uv_tcp_bind(&server, (const struct sockaddr*)&addr, 0);

    r = uv_listen((uv_stream_t*) &server, DEFAULT_BACKLOG, on_new_connection);

    if (r) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Listen error %s\n", uv_strerror(r));
        return 1;
    }
    return uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the issue is on `echo_read()`. When the TCP connection is terminated with tcp reset, nread is not -1, it's some negative number (-4095 in my case).
Was able to take care of it using `nread < 0` instead of `nread == -1`.

```
void echo_read(uv_stream_t *sock, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t *buf) {
    if (nread == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error echo_read");
        return;
    } else if (nread == 0) {
        uv_close((uv_handle_t*)sock, on_close);
        return;
    }
```